# Twilio - Unable to connect to service

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, twilio, twilio-php

I am using twilio php sdk in my ec2 ubuntu server. When i tried to make a signing key, twilio is giving an exception: `"Unable to connect to service"`.
This is my code

```
require_once 'path-to-sdk/Services/Twilio.php';
try{
    $sid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
    $key = $client->account->signing_keys->create(array("FriendlyName" => "test"));

    $signingKeySid =  $key->sid;
    $signingKeySecret = $key->secret;
    echo $signingKeySid." || ".$signingKeySecret;
} catch(Exception $e){
    die("error : ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

When i traced the error, it comes from `Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php;`

I tried this same code in my another ec2 ubuntu server. It works fine. 
**Is this a problem with ssl?**

Comment: Are there any differences between this ec2 ubuntu server and the one on which this API call works?

Comment: I had checked apache2 config between two servers. Server having twilio problem is giving these errors: 1) **"AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-xx-xx-xx-xx"** 2)  
**"AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"**. Any idea to resolve this error.

Comment: I don't know much about Apache I'm afraid. Might be worth asking another question that concentrates on that issue rather than on the Twilio aspect of it.

Comment: I had resolved the apache issue. But still twilio error persists.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that, if this code works on one of your servers then neither the code nor Twilio is the issue. There must be another difference between your servers that is causing this problem and I would try to find that.

Comment: Resolved. Need to install php curl.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Need to install php curl.